# "Term Vector API" clarification required

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not sure if I've understood the [Term Vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/docs-termvectors.html) correctly.

The document starts by saying:

> Returns information and statistics on terms in the fields of a particular document. The document could be stored in the index or artificially provided by the user. Term vectors are realtime by default, not near realtime. This can be changed by setting `realtime` parameter to false.

I'm guessing, **term** here is refered to what some other people would call a **token** maybe? Or is **term** defined by the time we get here in the documentation and I've missed it?

Then the document continues by saying there are three sections to the return value: **Term information**, **Term Statistics**, and **Field statistics**. I guess meaning that *term* information and statistics is not the only thing this API returns, correct?

Then **Term information** includes a field called `payloads`, which is not defined and I have no idea what it means.

Then in **Field statistics**, there is *sum of document frequencies* and *sum of total term frequencies* with a rather confusing explanation:

> Setting field_statistics to false (default is true) will omit :
>
> document count (how many documents contain this field)
>
> sum of document frequencies (the sum of document frequencies for all terms in this field)
>
> sum of total term frequencies (the sum of total term frequencies of each term in this field)

I guess they are simply the sum over their corresponding values reported in *term statistics*?

Then in the section **Behavior** it says:

> The term and field statistics are not accurate. Deleted documents are not taken into account. The information is only retrieved for the shard the requested document resides in. The term and field statistics are therefore only useful as relative measures whereas the absolute numbers have no meaning in this context. By default, when requesting term vectors of artificial documents, a shard to get the statistics from is randomly selected. Use `routing` only to hit a particular shard.

So which one is it? Realtime or not? Or is it that *term information* is realtime and *term statistics* and *field statistics* are merely an approximation of the reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm guessing, term here is refered to what some other people would call a token maybe? Or is term defined by the time we get here in the documentation and I've missed it?

`term` and `token` are synonyms and simply mean whatever came out of the analysis process and has been indexed in the Lucene inverted index.

> Then the document continues by saying there are three sections to the return value: Term information, Term Statistics, and Field statistics. I guess meaning that term information and statistics is not the only thing this API returns, correct?

By default, the call returns term information and field statistics, but term statistics have to be requested explicitly with `&term_statistics=true`.

> Then Term information includes a field called payloads, which is not defined and I have no idea what it means.

`payload` is a Lucene concept, which is pretty well explained [here](https://lucidworks.com/2009/08/05/getting-started-with-payloads/). Term payloads are not available unless your have a custom analyzer that makes use of a [delimited-payload](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-delimited-payload-tokenfilter.html) token filter to extract them.

> Then in Field statistics, there is sum of document frequencies and sum of total term frequencies with a rather confusing explanation:
>
> [...]
>
> I guess they are simply the sum over their corresponding values reported in term statistics?

The sum of "document frequencies" is the number of times each term present in the field appears in the same document. So if the field contains "big brown fox", it will count the number of times "big" appears in the same document, the number of times "brown" appears in the same document and the same for "fox".

The sum of "total term frequencies" is the number of times each term present in this field appears in all documents present in the Lucene index (which is located on a single shard of an ES index). So if the field contains "big brown fox", it will count the number of times "big" appears in all documents, the number of times "brown" appears in all documents and the same for "fox".

> So which one is it? Realtime or not? Or is it that term information is realtime and term statistics and field statistics are merely an approximation of the reality?

It is realtime by default, which means that a [refresh call](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) is made when issuing the `_termvectors` call in order to get fresh information from the Lucene index. However, statistics are gathered only from a single shard, which does not give an overall view of the statistics of the whole ES index (potentially made of several shards, hence several Lucene indexes).